# Duda sobre comparación de datos entre dos arrays

Tags: javascript, array

Estoy practicando comparar y almacenar resultados entre dos arrays. No entiendo los motivos, pero me imprime un resultado que no alcanzo a entender.

```
var alumnosAlgebra = [003,045,125,087,102,076,042,099];
var alumnosAnalisis= [125,042,031,023,099,087];
var alumnosComunes = [];

for(let i=0; i<alumnosAlgebra.length;i++){
    for(let f=0;f<alumnosAnalisis.length;f++){
        if(alumnosAlgebra[i]== alumnosAnalisis[f]){
            alumnosComunes.push(alumnosAlgebra[i]);
        }}}
console.log(alumnosComunes);
```

La consola me imprime

> [125, 87, 34, 99]

pero el 34 no está en lo arrays originales que comparo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando en tu código escribís un número con un `0` adelante, se interpreta en base 8.
`042` en base 8 es igual a `34` en decimal.

```js
let numero = 042;
console.log(numero);
```

Basta con sacarle los ceros que tenés adelante de cada número para que veas el resultado esperado.

- Fijate que no tuviste problemas con los otros dos números, `087` y `099`
  porque los interpreta directamente en base 10 ya que no son válidos en base 8

  (no pueden tener dígitos mayores a `7`).

Comment: Muchas gracias. Soy periodista y esto me pilla muy ajeno. Investigaré sobre el tema.

Comment: Entonces pensalo de esta forma: si lo que es escribís es en binario e ingresás un `11`, no es un un once sino un tres (`3`) en decimal... Bueno, en base 8 es lo mismo, después del `7` viene el `10` (que no es un diez sino un ocho).